# WPF TextBox content not updated when the round trip by the view model change the actual value

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, uri, .net-4.5

I have below WPF TextBox:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0"
         Grid.Row="1" 
         Text="{Binding myPath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                 
         Margin="5,8,8,5" />
```

And its property in the view model is:

```
public string myPath
{
   get => myObject.path;
   set
   {
       // Do some comprobations before assigning the new value
       if (comprobationsOk(value))
       {
          Uri myUri = new Uri(value);
          myObject.path = myUri.LocalPath;
          this.OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }
}
```

And this is my OnPropertyChanged method in my ViewModelBase class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

As you can see, the actual view model value is transformed in the setter.

When the user starts typing in the TextBox `///my/absolute/path` the property in the view model gets `//my/absolute/path`.
So I expect the `TextBox` to be updated with `//my/absolute/path`, but it is not and remains as `///my/absolute/path`

Comment: can you show us 'this.OnPropertyChanged()' method ?

Comment: Are you sure `comprobationsOk` is true, it's unrelated to `value`...

Comment: @Orace I have updated the post. Sorry

Comment: @J.Memisevic see my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works pretty well with a working view model.

*View:*

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

*View model:*

```
public class ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _name = string.Empty;

    public string Path
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            // To avoid constant System.UriFormatException, we use the try method
            var newValue = Uri.TryCreate(value, UriKind.Absolute, out var result) ? result.LocalPath : value;
            Update(ref _name, newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

*NotifyPropertyChangedBase :*

```csharp
public abstract class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected void Update<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(field, newValue))
            return;

        field = newValue;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case doing an Update(ref myObject.path, myUri.LocalPath) it is throwing a compilation error: CS0206 A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter. myObject.path is a property

Comment: My point is, that it work as is: the text box content is updated correctly in a round trip.
The code you provide doesn't strictly follow the MVVM pattern. The [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) of the VM is to expose property and notify on changes. It should not do `comprobations`; that's the work of the model.
You have to adapt it to the proposed solution.

Comment: I suspect your issue to be in the `comprobationsOk(value)` call that probably returning `false`.  Based on that, this question should be closed: not reproducible, was caused by a typo.

Comment: I have checked and comprobationsOk(value) returns true and OnPropertyChanged() is being called.

Comment: You said that `myObject.path` is a property . Besides the naming convention and MVVM pattern violations; are you sure that this property doesn't do criptik stuff too? like not being updated on a `set` because of `someBooleanFromThere` is not true? You didn't provide a minimum reproductible exemple, this looks like a *debug this program from partial code parts* hell.

Comment: I think I know what is happening.This TextBox contains a path and I have done a input check so that if you type in extra forward|backward slashes then I remove them. I do this in the view model. After removing those extra slashes I update myObject.path and I call OnPropertyChanged. Then previous myObject.path has the same value as the current one I am assigning now after removing extra slashes, so TextBox is not updated and TextBox remains with the path with extra slashes.

Comment: For example, If I type in C:\\path\\to\\filename.txt in the TextBox I would like TextBox to be updated with the value I set in view model in myObject.path after removing slashes, that is, I want TextBox to be updated to C:\path\to\filename.txt So in this case, how can I force TextBox to be updated despite myObject.path has the same  value as the one I am currently setting?